# How to completely deactivate the TouchID button on 2018 Intel MacBook Pro

Tags: keyboard, command-line, power, touch-id

I recently had an issue involving liquid poured over the top right corner of my keyboard, thus going under the TouchID button.

Since then, at random times, my MacBook auto-locks itself and then shuts down, and I can't do anything about it.

I suspect a short-circuit in the button hardware, causing my Mac to think I'm holding the button because I want to shut it down.

Is there a way to prevent that using commands, or is it a hardware problem only ?

(My Mac is not covered by warranty anymore, and the Genius Bar asks for around €1,400 to repair it, since the liquid has apparently gone over some key parts as well, but in my day to day use the only problem is this shutting down thing.)

Thanks !

Comment: To prevent locking, you could turn off the `Use TouchID sensor for Unlocking Your Mac` setting in System Preferences. It's under the `TouchID` preference pane.

Comment: Hi,
 Have you tried this solution https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430524/macbook-pro-disable-lock-on-touch-id-press ?